# singly linked list operation insert at a particular position

Tags: c, visual-studio

I wrote a program to perform singly linked list operation `insert at a particular position` **now there is no nodes at the moment , when I give the the input: 3 to the question `enter the position to be inserted` it shows runtime error**

```
void insert_pos()
    {
        struct node * temp, *loc;
        int item,pos,len;
        printf("enter the position to be insertd :");
        scanf("%d", &pos);
        if (pos == 1)
        {
            insert_beg();
        }
        else
        {
            len = length();
            if (start == NULL)
            {
                insert_beg();
            }
            else if (pos > len)
            {
                insert_end();
            }
            else
            {
                newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                printf("enter the data :");
                scanf("%d", &item);
                newnode->data = item;
                int i;
                temp = start;
                loc = temp->next;
                for (i = 1; i < pos - 1; i++)
                {
                    temp = temp->next;
                    loc = loc->next;
                }
                temp->next = newnode;
                newnode->next = loc;
            }
        }
    }
    int length()
    {
        int k = 1;
        struct node * temp;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            k++;
        }
        return k;
    }
```

**out put**

```
1.insert @ beg
2.insert @ end
3.insert @ perticular pos
4.display
5.exit
enter your option :3
enter the position to be inserted :3
```

**now a window pops up saying debug error**
pls help me with it

Comment: The "runtime error" is a crash. You solve them by first finding out where in your code the crash happens. You do that by running in a debugger and catching the crash "in action". When in the debugger, and having caught the crash, you can examine the values of involved variables to see if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: your `int length()` function invokes UB: `struct node *temp` contains garbage, it's not a valid pointer. You then dereference it (`temp->next`)... that's never going to behave as you want it to

Comment: But here's a hint for you: Uninitialized variables have *indeterminate values*, and using them leads to *undefined behavior*, which is a common cause of crashes.

Comment: Also: `(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))` <-- Note that, because you're using a C++ compiler, the cast is required, but if you use standard C, casting the return of `malloc` & co is frowned upon

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the tip ! I understood my mistake I Uninitialized `start = temp;` and it worked

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am using a c compiler

Comment: @steventhomas: The visual-c++ tag is pointless, then. And in that case: don't cast the return of `malloc` & co

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem sorry about that , I removed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was here the temp was Uninitialized

```
int length()
{
    int k = 1;
    struct node * temp;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        k++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

the fix was to assign `temp = start;`

**corrected program**

```
int length()
{
    int k = 1;
    struct node * temp;
    temp=start;  // start is a global variable
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        k++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

thanks every one for the tips !!!

Comment: Unless `start` is a global variable, that's still going to be an issue (as are `insert_beg` and `insert_end` BTW). The best thing to do here is to _pass the pointer to the list_ as an argument: `int length(struct node *list) { int k = 0; if (list == NULL) return k; while(list->next != NULL) { k++; list = list->next; } return k;}`

Comment: yaa start is a global variable